# Partial class property on Entity Framework entity has no Metadata in Breeze

Tags: entity-framework, breeze, asp.net-web-api

I have a property on my "Contact" entity:

```
public partial class Contact
{
    public string FullName { get { return this.FirstName + this.LastName; } set { } }
}
```

I then use breeze get the Contact data from my Web API function that returns Contacts. My data returned from my Web API call has the "FullName" property and the correct value coming down to the client, but my "Metadata" does not have the "FullName" property anywhere in it. What do I need to do to get the Metadata?

Answer (score 0):

I found no sensible solution to adding partial class items to the metatata from the server.  My opinion is that this should be considered as a bug to the server Breeze metadata function.
However the extended items data do get served from the server.
So if you add the extended properties manually on the client metadata-store, everything should be fine.
Here is an example how you do it in the javascript client code:

```
var man = new breeze.EntityManager(myServiceName);
man.metadataStore.registerEntityTypeCtor('Contact', function () { this.FullName = ''; });
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't really want that computed properties coming over the wire, do you? Why do you have a setter? This is a read-only property. And if this is an EF Code First class, how did you keep EF from believing that `FullName` is mapped to a "FullName" column in the "Contact" table?

I'm going to assume that you don't actually want the "FullName" to come over the wire. You want to extend the type with either a custom `EntityType` constructor or an initializer. I think you want an initializer in this case.

Take a look at "[Extending Entities](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/extending-entities#add-computed-to-initializer)" which happens to illustrate the recommended technique with a `fullName` property.

Comment: I'm getting the same problem - on an EF Model First class,  with a partial class built to extend it with some useful properties on the server (note: my extended properties don't have setters). Either breeze should generate metadata for these extra properties or it should not serialise them.